# Toggle img in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, toggle

So, I'm a newbie and I have a logical error that I can't figure out. I am trying to write a page for displaying numbers called in a bingo game. I have a table with 16 rows and 5 columns to accommodate the header and each possible bingo number. I want the user to be able to click the button and toggle an img that will display the number called. Here's a snippet:

```
<tr>
   <td><button onclick="toggle('picture')">B-1</button>
      <div id="picture" style="display:none"><img src="B1.png"/></div></td>
   <td><button onclick="toggle('picture')">I-16</button>
      <div id="picture" style="display:none"><img src="I16.png"/></div></td>
   <td><button onclick="toggle('picture')">N-31</button>
      <div id="picture" style="display:none"><img src="N31.png"/></div></td>  
</tr>
```

To toggle, I have the following js code:

```
function toggle(id) {
   var element = document.getElementById(id);  
    if(element.style.display == "none")
       show(id);
    else
       hide(id);}

function show(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";}

function hide(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";}
```

So, no matter which button I click, B1 toggles, but nothong else does.
I understand that the problem is (I think) what I am passing to the function. What do I pass so that the function only operates on the button that I'm using to call it?

If someone could help me get the correct code so that it works, that would be great, but if you could help me out with a little explanation so that I can understand it, that would be even better! Thank you in advance!

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: duplicate ID's === Identity-theft for DOM Objects... they don't like it. besides: instead of passing the ID around, and querying the DOM over and over, why not pass a reference to the DOM node around, which would _significantly_ reduce overhead

Comment: Thank you. It works and even better, I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Id must be unique try like this :

```
<td><button onclick="toggle('B1.png')">B-1</button>
      <div id="B1.png" style="display:none"><img src="B1.png"/></div></td>
   <td><button onclick="toggle('I16.png')">I-16</button>
      <div id="I16.png" style="display:none"><img src="I16.png"/></div></td>
   <td><button onclick="toggle('N31.png')">N-31</button>
      <div id="N31.png" style="display:none"><img src="N31.png"/></div></td>  

function toggle(id) {
   var element = document.getElementById(id);  
    if(element.style.display == "none"){
       element.style.display = "block";
    }else{
       element.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/SPyVB/

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td><button onclick="toggle('picture1')">B-1</button>
     <div id="picture1" style="display:none"><img src="B1.png"/></div></td>
     <td><button onclick="toggle('picture2')">I-16</button>
     <div id="picture2" style="display:none"><img src="I16.png"/></div></td>
     <td><button onclick="toggle('picture3')">N-31</button>
     <div id="picture3" style="display:none"><img src="N31.png"/></div></td>  
  </tr> 
</table>
```

javascript:

```
function toggle(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id);  
  if(element.style.display == "none")
   element.style.display = "block";
  else
   element.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

2 things. The IDs must be unique, and the way you have it set up you need to pass them to your function.

```
<tr>
   <td><button onclick="toggle('picture1')">B-1</button>
      <div id="picture1" style="display:none"><img src="B1.png"/></div></td>
   <td><button onclick="toggle('picture2')">I-16</button>
      <div id="picture2" style="display:none"><img src="I16.png"/></div></td>
   <td><button onclick="toggle('picture3')">N-31</button>
      <div id="picture3" style="display:none"><img src="N31.png"/></div></td>  
</tr>
```

Comment: You are passing a variable to the function but not defining it in arguments

Comment: i didn't read it right i thought it was all the same HTML element. When you slick something in js it has the scope of the element you clicked, which can be referenced with "this". If you were to write this in a more modular way you would probably use that "this" as an anchor to find the picture it corresponds to. In terms of widget design, it's generally considered better practice than passing variables unnecessarily.